# Hide a div everyday except Thursday

Tags: javascript, html, hide

Trying to hid the following div everyday except Thursday using this script.  Can't get it to work.  JS is still new, so what did I do wrong?

```
<div class="row">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        onload=function(){
            var rightNow = new Date();
            var day = rightNow.getDay();
            var hour = rightNow.getHours();
            var newDisplay = 'none'; // unless we see otherwise
            if(day==1  ||  day==2  ||  day==3  ||  day==5  || day==6 | day==7 ) {  // days hidden 
                if((hour>= 1) && (hour<= 24)) {
                  newDisplay = 'block';
        }
        }
        document.getElementById('thursday').style.display = newDisplay;
        }
        </script>

        <div class="col-md-12" id="thursday">

            <h3 style="font-family:Capture it;text-align:center">Warrior Pointe Radio - Live tonight on AllradioX -  1900 Pacific / 2200 Eastern</h3>   

        </div>
```

Comment: What are you checking the hour for? Must it be a specific hour of the day on Thursday or all day?

Comment: No, really I want it to show all day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are setting `display` to `none` initially, you'll want to only check if it's Thursday to set it to `block`. You can take out the `hour` stuff as well. Here's the final code:

```
onload = function(){
    var day = (new Date()).getDay();
    var newDisplay = 'none'; // unless it's Thursday
    if(day == 4) newDisplay = 'block';
    document.getElementById('thursday').style.display = newDisplay;
};
```